# My json file URL is not found in my angular server

Tags: json, angular, http, server

so i m making a server that s gonna be based on reading products from a json file using http

the problem is that when i build the application this error appears
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

this is my service code product.service.ts

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { IProduct } from './product/produit';



@Injectable()
export class ProductdataService {
private _productUrl:string='./product/products.json'
constructor(private _http:Http) {
}

getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
  return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
      .map((response : Response)=><IProduct[]> response.json())
      .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
      .catch(this.handleError);
}


  private handleError(error:Response)
  {console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server Error')

  }

}
```

and this is my json File :

```js
[{  
    "idpr":1,   
    
    "productName": "The Alchemist",
    "description":"Paulo Coelho's enchanting novel has inspired a devoted following around the world." ,
    "imgUrl":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41MeC94AxIL._SX324_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg" ,
    "price":10.5,
    "starRating":3,
    "author":"Paulo Coelho",
    "category":"Litterature"
      
     }
     ,{    
      "idpr":2,   
      "productName": "Cry From The Grave",
      "description":"After a heartbreaking tragedy six years ago, Hannah Walker is struggling to pick up the pieces of her life – until a chance discovery tips her whole world upside down again. " ,
      "imgUrl":"https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61ehavtz8SL._SY346_.jpg" ,
      "price":5.25,
      "starRating":3,
      "author":" Carolyn Mahony",
      "category":"Thriller"
        
       },{    
        "idpr":3,   
        "productName": "You are the Best Wife",
        "description":"Ajay believes in living for himself; Bhavna teaches him to live for others. Ajay is a planner for life Bhavna makes him live in every moment." ,
        "imgUrl":"https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51QELCohn6L.jpg" ,
        "price":3.5,
        "starRating":3,
        "author":" Ajay Pandey ",
        "category":"Romance"
          
         }, 
  {    
    "idpr":4, 
        "productName": "Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde",
        "description":"Mr. UTTERSON the lawyer was a man of a rugged countenance that was never lighted by a smile" ,
        "imgUrl":"https://ia801606.us.archive.org/zipview.php?zip=/26/items/olcovers36/olcovers36-L.zip&file=368462-L.jpg" ,
        "price":3.48,
        "starRating":3,
        "author":" Robert Louis Stevenson",
        "category":"Science"
          
         }
    ]
```

and this where i placed my json file so that the url in the service will be : './product/products.json'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfG2W.jpg)

plzz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That json file won't be included in the built app. It needs to be located in the folder where the compiled output of your code is (or you can add it to the assets folder if you use angular-cli)